# CSS overflow-y : auto does not reach the bottom of div

Tags: css, overflow

I have random number of list items floating left inside the following div. The problem is, when the items overflows in vertical direction, scroll does not get to the bottom only reaching as far as the half of the last item's height. In other words, I cannot see the full list of items when the items overflow in the following div. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
.div {

    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 80px;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

Comment: Can you add your html as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some padding-bottom to your last item..